# Как отформатировать строку period = start.until(end); Java

Tags: java

```
LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 1);
LocalDate currDay = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(birthday.until(currDay));
```

Я получаю P16Y9M3D, а хочу 16*12+9 месяцев и 3 дня

Answer (score 3):

Вместо использования стандартного преобразования к строке (неявного вызова метода `toString`) сначала сохраните период в отдельную переменную, получите из неё нужные свойства и выведите строку:

```
Period period = birthday.until(currDay);
System.out.println(period.getYears() * 12 + period.getMonths() + " месяцев и " + period.getDays() + " дня");
```

Последнее можно заменить на:

```
System.out.printf("%d месяцев и %d дней", period.getYears() * 12 + period.getMonths(), period.getDays());
```